# Read specific row in csv

Tags: java, csv

Is there any way through which we can read specific row record on the basis of value. For example my csv file is:

```
ProductID,ProductName,price,availability,type
12345,Anaox,300,yes,medicine
23456,Chekmeter,400,yes,testing
```

I want to get the row whose ProductID is ‘23456’. i was checking the `new CsvReader(“D:\products.csv”).getRawRecord()` method, but it doesn’t have any method parameters.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just iterating though the file?

Comment: You must code that. openCSV has everything you need. Read it row by row and test the value of the column like this value.equalsIgnoreCase("23456")

Comment: Thing is i don't want to iterate. Because if my file has 1000 records then to get a row which is on 999th position i have to iterate 998 records which is not a performent solution.

Comment: Is your CSV sorted by ProductID? Then you can do some kind of binary search. If not you have to iterate because how do you know this row is on 999th row? Only when you check all 998 rows before.

Comment: CSV isn't a database, you'll need to iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator iterator = CsvReader("D:\\products.csv").Iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    if((String[] string = (iterator.next))[0] == 23456)
        sout("Found the row: " + string[0] + ", " + string[1] + ", " + string[2] + ", " + string[3] + ", " + string[4]);
}
```

And regarding your concern about performance:

1. with 1.000 elements this will still be way faster than you need it to be, worry when you get to 1.000.000 elements
2. If you want the reading of the Csv to be performant you gotta use a performant way of storing your IDs. If you are just incrementing your IDs everytime a new one is made and never delete an ID you can use the ID as an index to directly  get the correct line.

Comment: The method Iterator() is undefined for the type CsvReader. I'm using below library import com.csvreader.CsvReader;
import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;

Comment: Google CsvReader, youll find the Java Documentation on it, there you find the method iterator whivh should give you String arrays.

Comment: The code was thrown together just as something to show you for understanding, not for exact copy pasting

Comment: There seems to be multiple Java "implementations" of CsvReader; maybe your answer should specify which one you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static ArrayList<String> getSpecificRowData(String s) throws IOException 
        {
            String csvFile = s;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    
                    //write your row name in the given csv file
                    if(line.contains("write your row name"))
                    {
                        arr.add(line);
                    }     
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arr;  
        }

//return the row in the form of ArrayList

ArrayList<String> li=getSpecificRowData("FileName12.csv");
        System.out.println(li);
```